# bit manipulation - only change last 4 bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to set the last 4 bits of an int to another int.

So for example you have this int: `1100 0001`. And I only want to change the last four bits with another int for example: `0000 0110`. All the other bits should remain unchanged and it has to be in one statement (I'm sorry for my horrible explanation).

The folowing statement does work, but it seems bad practice and It would only work with an `uint8_t`

```
unint8_t count = 6; //0000 0110
PORTC = ((PORTC >> 4) << 4) | count; //PORTC = 1100
```

The outcome of PORTC is `1100 0110` and this is what I want, however I want it to work with any integer. What is another (better) way of doing this?

NOTE: It **must** be one statement.

Comment: From one operation, do you mean can be written in one statement? Aren't right shift, left shift and then ORing three operations in total?

Comment: Not sure how your 'working' example conforms to the single operation requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, one statement. Will change it in the question.

Comment: `It would only work with an uint8_t` no, why?

Comment: @KamilCuk Well, now I think about it... I asked my teacher first and that's what he told me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ll first want to AND the destination number with a mask that has all but 4 lowest bits set, then OR that with the lowest 4 bits of the first number.

```
PORTC = (PORTC & ~0xfULL) | ( count & 0xf );
```